# How to recognize the use of 'that' in 'the way that events evolve but remain the same.'?

Tags: grammar

> They denote states, which do not develop over time in different phases
> **the way that** events evolve but remain the same.

Merriam-Webster defines:

> (4)-> used as a function word to introduce a subordinate clause modifying
> an adverb or *adverbial expression*

By this definition, can ‘that’ be replaced with 'in which'? So as in

> There are many reporting verbs which you can use to show **the way in**
> **which** something was said.

Comment: That is correct.  (BTW, *that* does seem to be overused and difficult to parse in English. See https://www.englishclub.com/ref/esl/Power_of_7/7_Thats_2948.php for example.)

Comment: You might consider "by which" or "through which", or "the same way as". There are nuances but it's not very clear what your sentence means. You might also like a comma after evolve, as I assume the "that" clause ends there.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I don't see any problem making that substitution (although I think you need a comma after *evolve*).